# Match the word "bar" if found anywhere in a field

Tags: regex, case, looker-studio, re2

I am trying to use a `CASE` statement in Google Data Studio to return a **Boolean** result if a given string is found within an existing field.

As Google Data Studio uses RE2 RegEx syntax, I believe the following would work, but it returns a `could not parse formula` error:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Foo, '(\W|^)bar(\W|$)') THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

I have tried many different combinations of RegEx syntax, but can't work it out. Any help would be much appreciated as this should be a simple `REGEXP_MATCH`?

The **Boolean** result should be `true` if the string is found anywhere within the field:

```
+---------------------------+----------------+
|            Foo            | Boolean Result |
+---------------------------+----------------+
| blah bar / boo doo        | True           |
| but is / should not match | False          |
| but match / here bar      | True           |
+---------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Try `REGEXP_MATCH(Foo, '(.*\W|^)bar(\W.*|$)')`

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work either?

Comment: Do you have line breaks inside? Then add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern. Also, I guess you need to double the backslashes, `'(.*\\W|^)bar(\\W.*|$)'`

Comment: It was the double back slash, thank you. If you can put that as the answer I can accept.

Comment: Try this `.*\bbar\b.*` or stringed `.*\\bbar\\b.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you match the whole string with the pattern that you want to use in a `REGEXP_MATCH` and when using regex escapes, make sure to double escape them:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Foo, '(.*\\W|^)bar(\\W.*|$)') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

If there are line breaks in `Foo`, add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern.

**Details**

- `(.*\\W|^)` - either any 0+ chars as many as possible followed with a non-word char or start of a string
- `bar` - the word
- `(\\W.*|$)` -  either a non-word char followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible or end of a string

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HDxqV4/1).

Answer (score 0):

A [Boolean](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9514333) field can be created using the single [`REGEXP_MATCH`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7064476) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) below, where `\\b` on either side of `bar` represents a **Word Boundary** thus matching `bar` but not `bark`, `embark` or `embar`:

```
REGEXP_MATCH(Foo, ".*(\\bbar\\b).*")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/f9895bc9-1c15-445e-b9ac-e952d7bc9149) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]